# How to apply a color to a SVG Text element

Tags: html, css, text, svg

Okay... I'm going nuts over here. I've started experimenting with SVG. Working with SVG and applying CSS classes to it works like a charm. I just cant figure out what i'm doing wrong, but i just cant get the class to work on a svg text element. I've stripped it all the way down and this is what i got:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Playground</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        .mainsvg {
            height: 320px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            width: 400px;
        }
        .caption {
            color: yellow;
        }
    </style>
    <h2>SVG - Sandbox</h2>
    <div>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" class="mainsvg">
            <text x="65" y="40" class="caption">Fact</text>
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#ClassAttribute this should work...

Any hints/tips on what to change, or an alternative?

Comment: If I read the w3 link you're not able to set border. it's called stroke.

Comment: Well, the border works just fine. Stroke is used for everything you actually "draw". But my question is about the class on the text element, where I set the color of the text just like in the w3 link.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Setting the class is correct but the CSS color property has no effect on SVG. SVG uses [fill](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillProperty) and [stroke](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#StrokeProperties) properties. In your case you probably just need to change color to fill. This displays yellow text for me in Firefox.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Playground</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        .mainsvg {
            height: 320px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            width: 400px;
        }
        .caption {
            fill: yellow;
        }
    </style>
    <h2>SVG - Sandbox</h2>
    <div>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" class="mainsvg">
            <text x="65" y="40" class="caption">Fact</text>
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried it and nope... And remember. Color is what they give as an example at W3 Recommendation. I stripped it down to color to get the easiest possible implementation to test with.

Comment: Well done you've found a bug in the SVG specification. I've reported it to w3c: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-svg/2013Jul/0001.html

Comment: Well, no. I agree that there is a bug. But it's not in the documentation. They basicly state what it is supposed to be. It just seems that all browsers failed to implement this. Which strikes me as very unlikely. And remember, it doesn't work with fill or stroke either. It seems the css class selector is completely ignored (chrome, FF and IE10).

Comment: Wait.... text.caption does work. text .caption (with space) does not.... (this is tested with fill in all 3 browsers)
.caption works aswell. I wonder what I tested the first time you suggested fill and it did not work.....

Comment: I figured out where I went wrong. I'm trying to set the scale with JQuery to the text block. Adding "-webkit-transform: scale(2)" to the style works perfectly. When adding it dynamicly with jQuery ($('.caption').css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(2)');) it does not.
I also change the color with JQuery, and that works just fine. So I guess jQuery doesn't handle handle transforms the way i thought it did. Well, thanks anyway. My original question inhere is solved !

Comment: Setting just the `color` property has no directly visible effect in svg, but you can use that color for the `fill`, `stroke` or even both, e.g `text { fill: currentColor }`.

Comment: this worked for me stroke="blue"

Answer (score 7):

This is the top Google result for coloring SVG text and to make it very clear for rookies like me, to color an SVG text element in 2022, use stroke, and fill.

```
fill="red"
stroke="#0000FF"
```

Just like you use stroke for the outline color and fill for the inside color of a shape, you can do the same thing for text in SVGs.

And the best news is, if you use `fill="currentColor"` instead of a hard coded color, you can set the SVG text with CSS.

```
svg {
    color: red;
}
```

Click run code snippet to see an example right in this answer.

```html
<svg height="202" width="202">
      <circle cx="101" cy="101" r="100"
              stroke="red"
              stroke-width="1"
              fill="none"
              />

<!-- fill="currentColor" if you want to use CSS to set the color of SVG text -->
      <text x="100" y="100" 
            text-anchor="middle"
            fill="red"
            stroke="#0000FF"
            stroke-width="1px"
            alignment-baseline="middle"
            font-variant="all-small-caps"
            font-size="25"
            font-weight="bold" 
            >
        Font is Colored
      </text>
```

Comment: Can you address the question, which is about using CSS to apply to SVG text?

Comment: @JGC missed that part. Added the fill="currentColor" section and updated the code sample. thanks

Comment: Upvoted for `alignment-baseline: middle`

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me either, so I did more research, and found a solution.
If you wrap the SVG `<text .../>` element in an `<g .../>` (group) element it can work:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" class="mainsvg">
  <g class="caption">
    <text x="65" y="40" fill="currentcolor">Fact</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

This applies the CSS to the `<g>`, and then the `<text>` element inherits the `currentcolor` of the parent into its `fill` (or `stroke`).

Answer (score 0):

I simply put fill in the text element of the SVG

```
<svg style="fill: ${color};" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                        width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 1280.000000 1280.000000"
                                        preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
                                        <g transform="translate(0.000000,1280.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
                                            stroke="none">
                                            <path d="M3684 12777 c29 -118 741 -2470 911 -3012 166 -528 325 -978 394
                                                -1113 l20 -40 -67 -40 c-123 -73 -168 -161 -204 -396 -24 -165 -41 -222 -80
                                                -281 -42 -63 -104 -107 -293 -210 -169 -92 -325 -187 -440 -269 -1271 -908
                                                -1841 -2501 -1435 -4007 272 -1004 956 -1857 1880 -2342 390 -205 806 -336
                                                1275 -403 177 -25 633 -30 835 -9 858 87 1630 446 2239 1039 633 618 1012
                                                1405 1107 2299 20 189 14 660 -10 832 -77 540 -243 1020 -502 1450 -372 616
                                                -861 1073 -1526 1425 -292 155 -332 205 -372 465 -38 243 -81 340 -178 401
                                                -30 19 -38 30 -33 42 60 142 169 496 279 910 146 545 826 3241 826 3272 0 7
                                                -290 10 -902 10 l-903 0 -82 -328 c-236 -938 -333 -1319 -340 -1334 -7 -14
                                                -252 794 -489 1610 l-16 52 -950 0 -950 0 6 -23z m1474 -4452 l32 -45 638 0
                                                c351 0 768 3 926 7 287 6 288 6 310 30 22 23 22 24 40 4 40 -44 24 -176 -28
                                                -239 -45 -53 -147 -65 -307 -37 -471 81 -904 80 -1383 -6 -191 -34 -270 -23
                                                -318 42 -49 65 -63 165 -32 217 14 24 70 72 84 72 4 0 20 -20 38 -45z" />
                                            <text id="letra_medalha" x="6100" y="-4000" font-family="Arial"
                                                font-size="4000" fill="${getContrastColor(color)}"
                                                text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle"
                                                dominant-baseline="middle" transform="rotate(180) scale(-1, 1)">
                                                ${post.medalha_titles[index]}
                                            </text>
                                        </g>
                                    </svg>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).